# Проблема в кнопках "Нормально" и "Сложно". Они не активируются. Помогите исправить код и найти ошибку. это моя первая программа

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

````
from telebot import types

Token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(Token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    bt1 = types.KeyboardButton("Уравнения")
    bt2 = types.KeyboardButton("Метадичка")
    markup.add(bt1, bt2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def ez(message):
    if message.text == "Уравнения":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Легко")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Нормально")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Сложно")
        back = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выберите уровень сложности", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Метадичка":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Pon")
    elif message.text == "Легко":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="111x^2-111x-111=0")
    elif message.text == "1":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Следующее уравнение")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Молодец, давай попробуем решить еще одно уравнение",reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Следующее уравнение":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="222x^2-222x-222=0")
    elif message.text == "2":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Молодец,приступай к следующему уровню", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Назад":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Легко")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Нормально")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Сложно")
        back = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выберите уровень сложности", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Вернуться в главное меню":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Уравнения")
        button2 = types.KeyboardButton("Метадичка")
        markup.add(button1, button2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в главное меню", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def norm(message):
    if message.text == "Нормально":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="333x^2-333x+333=0")
    elif message.text == "3":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Следующее уравнение")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Молодец, давай попробуем решить еще одно уравнение",reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Следующее уравнение":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="553x^2-333x+333=0")
    elif message.text == "4":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Следующее уравнение")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Молодец, давай попробуем решить еще одно уравнение",reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Вернуться в главное меню":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Уравнения")
        button2 = types.KeyboardButton("Метадичка")
        markup.add(button1, button2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в главное меню", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def hard(message):
    if message.text == "Сложно":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="555x^2-555x-555=0")
    elif message.text == "5":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Следующее уравнение(Сложно)")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Молодец, давай попробуем решить еще одно уравнение",reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Следующее уравнение(Сложно)":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="666x^2-666x-666=0")
    elif message.text == "6":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Назад")
        markup.add(btn1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Молодец,ты прошел все этапы", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Назад":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Легко")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Нормально")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Сложно")
        back = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в главное меню")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выберите уровень сложности", reply_markup=markup)
    elif message.text == "Вернуться в главное меню":
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        button1 = types.KeyboardButton("Уравнения")
        button2 = types.KeyboardButton("Метадичка")
        markup.add(button1, button2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в главное меню", reply_markup=markup)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)```
````